# Refactoring in rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have 4 actions in my controller and I have some conditions to be
checked inside each action. what is the best way to do so? For Eg. the condition to be checked for each action is below

```
if params[:id] == $boy.id
    @rec = $boy.name
  elsif params[:id] == $girl.id
  @rec = $girl.name
  else
    render :json=>{"Error"=> "Person with #{params[:id]} does not
exists"}  and return
  end
```

Comment: extract it to a `before_filter`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. Write a method that checks the conditions and return the result to the action that calls it.
2. `before_filter` but if you add more actions to your controller then you will have to add skip the before_filter for actions for which the condition need not be checked.

Example 1 :

```
 def check 
    if params[:id] == $boy.id
      @rec = $boy.name
    elsif params[:id] == $girl.id
      @rec = $girl.name
    else
      @json = {"Error"=> "Person with #{params[:id]} does not exists"}
      return @json
    end
 end

 def some_action
   result = check
   # Use your result in action 
 end
```

Example 2:

```
 before_filter: check, :only => [:some_action,:some_action2] //You can as well use except if you want this check to be avoided only for certain actions
  # Use the same definition of check here


 def some_action
    if @rec
      // you code here
    else @json
      // you code here
    end
 end
```

The only difference is that if you follow step one you will have to call the check method wherever you want to check the conditions. If you use the second option you specify the action that would use the `before_filter` right on the top.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails controller if want to execute some codes before/after for more than one action, you can use **filters**. in your case you can use **before filter**. The code look like this

```
before_filter :check_id
...

private:
 def check_id
  if params[:id] == $boy.id
    @rec = $boy.name
  elsif params[:id] == $girl.id
   @rec = $girl.name
  else
   render :json=>{"Error"=> "Person with #{params[:id]} does not exists"}  and  return
  end
 end
```

Comment: Can you add explanation in your answer?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#filters if you want to know more about filters